# qTip mouseover like gMail contacts

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, gmail, qtip

I am fairly new to qTip and so far things look awesome for implementing.

I am trying to setup my contacts to have a mouseover like gmail has when you mouse over a contact is shows their picture and specific actions.

I currently have the code loading dynamically with the position target set to mouse, and have the hide set to fixed:true.

But when I move the mouse the tooltip moves too, and I need it to stand still so I can click on actions inside the tooltip.

This is what I have so far.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   // Use the each() method to gain access to each of the elements attributes
   $('.contact').each(function()
   {
      $(this).qtip(
      {

       content: {
          method: 'GET',
           url: 'testData.php', 
          data: { 
             id: 1
          }
       },
         position: { target: 'mouse', 
                 adjust: { screen: true, scroll: true } },
       show: {
         delay: 700,
         solo: true 
       },
       hide: {
            fixed: true, // Make it fixed so it can be hovered over
         when: 'mouseout'
         },
         style: {
            padding: '5px 15px', // Give it some extra padding
            name: 'light' // And style it with the preset dark theme
         }

      });
   });

});
```

Any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, all I had to add was this:

```
position: { 
   target: 'mouse', 
   adjust: { screen: true, scroll: true, mouse: false } 
},
```